# is it possible to overwrite "self" to point to another object inside self.method in python?

Tags: python, python-c-api

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, o):
        # get wrapped object and do something with it
        self.o = o
    def fun(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self = self.o # here want to swap
        # or some low level C api like
        # some_assign(self, self.o)
        # so that it swaps id() mem addr to self.o
        return self.fun(*args, **kwargs) # and now it's class A

class A(object):
    def fun(self):
        return 'A.fun'

a = A()
w = Wrapper(a)
print(type(w)) # wrapper
print(w.fun()) # some operation after which I want to loose Wrapper
print(a is w) # this goes False and I'd like True :) 
             # so that this is the original A() object
```

Is there any way to do this in Python?

Comment: @outis Yes, getting: <class '__main__.Wrapper'>, A.fun, False

Comment: It is possible to do some weired stuf like this.  I'm not sure if I should tell you how, because people might start actually doing terrible things like this.

Comment: If I understand you right, you want an equivalent of Smalltalk's '#become:'? Googling for that gives me: http://wargle.blogspot.com/2009/07/smalltalks-become-in-python.html. (That said the code instills violent urges in me.)

Comment: @Inerdia: That code is not only disguisting, ut it doesn't even work for this purpose - the `is` will still be `False`.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assigning to `self` inside a method simply rebinds the local variable `self` to the new object.  Generally, an assignment to a bare name never changes any objects, it just rebinds the name on the left-hand side to point to the object on the right-hand side.

So what you would need to do is modify the object `self` points to to match the object `self.o` points to.  This is only possible if both `A` and `Wrapper` are new-style classes and none of them defines `__slots__`:

```
self.__class__ = self.o.__class__
self.__dict__ = self.o.__dict__
```

This will work in CPython, but I'm not sure about the other Python implementation.  And even in CPython, it's a terrible idea to do this.

(Note that the `is` condition in the last line of your code will still be `False`, but I think this does what you intend.)

Comment: Ah, this is the trick you were talking about. +1 For sheer cleverness, despite the fact it's terribly hideous.

Comment: And will fail miserably in many corner cases, for example if classes derive from C-types other than `object`.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. This would require pass by reference. You can change the local variable (more precisely, the parameter) `self` just fine, but doing that does not influence whatever location the reference passed as argument came from (such as your `w`).

And given the circumstances (implicitly passed `self`), it's not even possible to apply the usual hacks (such as using a single-element list and mutate `x[0]`). Even if such tricks would work (or if there's an even more obscure hack that *can* do this), they'd be highly discouraged. It goes against everything Python programmers are used to. Just make the `Wrapper` object *act as if* it was replaces (i.e. forward **everything** to `self.o`). That won't make identity checks succeed, but it's by far the simplest, cleanest and most maintainable solution.

Note: For the sake of experimenting, there is a nonstandard and absolutely nonportable PyPy extension which can do this (replacing an object *completely*): [`__pypy__.become`](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/objspace-proxies.html#the-thunk-object-space). Needless to say, it'd be extremely ill-advised to use it. Find another solution.

Comment: It is possible even in CPython, so "you can't" seems wrong.  It is a terrible idea, though.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Well, I'm not aware of anything (except of course writing C code that does it) the interpreter, and I'm already disturbingly familiar with such hacks. Still, I can't rule it out entirely, so I added a clause to cover that (even before your comment).

Comment: Added my own answer to explain how.  To be honest, it doesn't do exactly what the OP asked for.  +1 for the link to `__pypy__.become`, interesting.